# How to retrieve all results from NearBySearch on Azure?

Tags: azure, api, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, google-nearby

I am using NearBySearch from Microsoft Azure. In the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/get-search-nearby?tabs=HTTP) it says that when you make a query the **totalResults** that the API can return is X. However, you can also read that there is a **limit** on the number of items returned which is at most 100.

In the case that the **totalResults** >= **limit** == **100**, the API will only display the first 100 results, thus not showing the remaining ones.

**Question**: Would you be able to suggest a way to retrieve the additional results using the NearBySearch function?

**Note**: On the Google API NearBySearch there is a parameter called **next_page_token**, which allows to view all the possible results. Is there something similar in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a limit of 100 results each query. If you have 150 totalResults. You can execute the query with ofs= 0 and limit= 100 to get the first 100 entries. After that you execute the second query with the ofs=100 (because it is like an index). Your limit is 100. After that you will get the next 100 results. Because there are only 50 results left, your numResults will be 50.

I hope it is understandable

Answer (score 0):

> Would you be able to suggest a way to retrieve the additional results
> using the NearBySearch function?

Looking at the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/get-search-nearby?tabs=HTTP), I noticed that there is an offset parameter (`ofs`) which by default is zero. You should be able to use that to get the next set of results if the total results are more than the limit specified by you.

[image]

Comment: Oh nice catch thanks!! But I still see that there is a maximum value of 1900. What if the total result is greater than this value?

Comment: I have not used this service and answered the question by reading the documentation. Based on my understanding, I think 1900 is the hard limit. I guess you would need to tweak your other search parameters to keep the total results under 1900.